# A table row was 2 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (3)

Tags: html

I used https://validator.w3.org/nu/#file to correct my html for class but I keep getting this error

Warning: A table row was 2 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (3).
From line 31, column 31; to line 32, column 6
ring  ↩    ↩

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Assignment 3B</title>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
th, td {
    width: 25%;
}
th {
    height: 50px
}
th, td {
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>

    <tr>
    <th colspan="3"> Seasons </th> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <td rowspan="3"> March/April </td>
    <th rowspan="4"> Spring </th> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td > <b> Cold </b></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td> Warm </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
    <th rowspan="1">
    <img src="tree1.png" alt="tree" style="width:150px;height:150px;"> 
    </th>
    <td style="background-image: url(Light_Pink_430051_i0.png)"> <b>Warm </b> </td>
    </tr>

    </table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me

Comment: Please post an image how it suppose to look, as your code has structural errors when it comes to matching cols and rows

Comment: Please check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#More_Examples cause a `<th>` can only be in the first `<tr>` or in `<thead><tr>`

Comment: After seeing your comment about what you want it to look like feel like you would be better served using divs with widths and floats.

Comment: Oh. This is for school and you need to use tables?

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st row has 3 columns, 2nd and 5th row have 2 columns, 3rd and 4th row have 1 column

Try this html:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
th,
td {
  width: 25%;
}
th {
  height: 50px
}
th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Assignment 3B</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <!-- 2 columns only -->
      <th colspan="2">Seasons</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>March/April</th>
      <th>Spring</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <b> Cold </b>
      </td>
      <td>Warm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <img src="tree1.png" alt="tree" style="width:150px;height:150px;">
      </th>
      <td style="background-image: url(Light_Pink_430051_i0.png)"> <b>Warm </b> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is occurring because your selected `td` and `th` doesn't contain as much as column defined in the **rowspan**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to answer your school question for you but I will try to help you figure it out

So remember that rows go across and columns go up and down. When you define a table you define the table. Then the rows in the table and in each row you define each column.

So take that image and try to think of rows first

You got the first cell right. It spans 3 columns

Then in the next row. The first cell spans 2 rows, the second cell spans 3 rows and the third cell spans one row

In the next row you already handled the first and second cols and need to define the third cell

And in the last row you need to define the first cell, the second cell was already handled back in the second row. Then you need to define the last cell

Hope you can take it from there